# need help on how this is done with a Venn diagram

Tags: probability

There are 126 learners.  Of these learners, 44 take economics, 112 take mathematics and 90 take life sciences.  All the learners who take economics also take mathematics.  80 learners take mathematics and life sciences and 30 learners do economics and life sciences. Need help on how this is done with a Venn diagram.

1)If a learner is chosen at random:

1.1)The probability of a learner doing none of the subjects

1.2)The probability that a student takes mathematics but not life sciences

1.3)The probability that a student does mathematics or life sciences

1.4)P(M or L)

Answer (score 1):

HINT...The E circle lies entirely inside the M circle and the L circle intersects both.

Put 30 in the intersection of all three circles, so 80-30=50 goes in the intersection of L and M, but not E.

44-30=14 goes in the region inside the E circle, not in the L circle.

Now you know the total of M and the total of L so you should be able to complete the rest of the diagram

I have 4 people outside all three circles....